# Having a problem in datatables and fullcalendar scripts

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, fullcalendar

I am using dataTables and it is working properly no until i inlclude fullcalendar my dataTable suddenly didnt work and i found out that adding the fullcalendar scripts makes it somehow disabled here is my scripts

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fullcalendar -->
<script src="vendor/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

because both of them uses jquery.min.js i tried to use the same jquery on them the latest one but it didnt work. Does anybody know how to fix this thanks a lot.

Comment: I noticed that you have included the jQuery script multiple times. Use the jQuery script only once at the beginning. Could you please remove the jquery.min.js script inside the full calendar and let me know the problem is solved or not ?